# How to solve this literal equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have a literal equation that needs to be solved for $\theta$:

$$mg \sin(\theta) = \mu mg \cos(\theta)\left({ M+m \over m}\right)  $$

Comment: Do you mean $mg \sin \theta = umg \cos \theta \cdot \frac{M+m}{m}$?

Comment: Use $\sin x/\cos x=\tan x$ and the arctangent function.

Comment: @jay: Did I get it right? If so, you can use the "edit" button to see what I did to change the formatting. If not, say what's wrong and someone will fix it.

Comment: What is a «literal equation»?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It's an equation whose coefficients are letters instead of numbers, I guess. Such as $ax+b=0$, but not $2x-5=0$.

Comment: @jay [I wrote a tutorial / reference for the equation editor](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple rearrangement shows that
$$\tan\theta = \mu\left(1+\frac{M}{m}\right)$$
to obtain numerical values for the equation you'll need the ratio of the masses and the coefficient of friction, in which case you can simply take the arctangent.